# Python Requests Timeout Value error

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, python-requests, urllib3

Good Evening,

I cannot get my https request to go through. I'm having to use SSLv3, so I'm specifying the protocol with:

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
import ssl

class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
     def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                        maxsize=maxsize,
                                        block=block,
                                        ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)

username = 'username'
password = 'password'
email = 'email@example.com'
url = 'https://api.example.com/'
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
params = {'emailaddress': email}
auth = (username, password)

s = requests.Session()
s.mount(url, MyAdapter())
r = s.get(url+'customer.svc/search', params=params, auth=auth, headers=headers)
```

When I run my get request I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 473, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 517, in urlopen
    timeout_obj = self._get_timeout(timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 283, in _get_timeout
    return Timeout.from_float(timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 152, in from_float
    return Timeout(read=timeout, connect=timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 95, in __init__
    self._connect = self._validate_timeout(connect, 'connect')
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 125, in _validate_timeout
    "int or float." % (name, value))
ValueError: Timeout value connect was Timeout(connect=None, read=None, total=None), but it must be an int or float.
```

Any ideas? I can't figure it out.

Additional Context: I'm on an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu Instance, running requests 2.5.1 and python 2.7.6

Comment: I've run that exact code with both Python 2 and Python 3 and it runs perfectly for me. It looks like we'll need the full traceback and if possible all the relevant code

Comment: Updated original post.

Comment: What version of requests and urllib3? (Might be wiser to use the vendored urllib3 just to avoid incompatibility, requests.packages.urllib3 or somesuch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like requests doesn't always play nice when you bring in an outside urllib3 distribution. What I ended up doing was calling requests internal urllib3 instead.

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
```

instead of:

```
from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
```

No issues since I started doing this.