# upgrading urllib3 made cloud-init fail, apparently urllib3 and python requests have version compatibility issues?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3, cloud-init

We upgraded our python-urllib3 from 1.5-7 to 10.10.4-1 and started getting errors in Cloud-init when it tried to get AWS metadata:

`"unexpected error [cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects]".`

I've seen several other StackOverFlow issues pointing to incompatibility issues between urllib3 and requests ([Python Requests Timeout Value error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081911/python-requests-timeout-value-error)), ([Algolia reindex command fails with exception in urllib3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768429/algolia-reindex-command-fails-with-exception-in-urllib3)).

What I can't find is any matrix of the versions that **do** work together.  The solutions in the other questions aren't available to us as the invoking code is buried in CloudInit.

We don't really have the option of going back to our previous version of urllib3 because other package (ElasticSearch Curator) apparently requires the newer version.

Comment: need some Traceback code for re-editing base class. But my idea not only one bug !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests' ordinarily vendors its urllib3 dependency, but downstream packagers have a tendency to break requests and urllib3 apart. This means a given version of requests makes no guarantees about being compatible with any version of urllib3 other than the one that it was shipped with originally.

Whatever version is installed by default in your OS release is the only version of urllib3 that will work the version of requests installed by your OS.

If you require multiple different releases of Python libraries at the same time, I recommend you look into [virtual environments](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).